# Java compiling, "No such file or Directory"

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

using JNI i'm trying to let a C program works under java. Here's the issue.

First i created the java class testcli.java:

```
public class testcli {

    public native void stdErr();
    public native int cliFromC();


    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ctest"); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new testcli().stdErr();
        new testcli().cliFromC();

    }
```

Then compiled with

```
javac testcli.java
```

and created header with

```
javah testcli
```

after that created the librari ctest.c and compiled with

```
gcc -o libctest.so -shared -I/path/to/jni.h ctest.c -lc
```

and i got the libctest.so created, then added to bashrc the following code:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/Desktop/project2/thesys/src
```

and when i go to type

```
java testcli
```

it says me "No such file or directory".

I'm running java 8 oracle on a 32 bit machine with xubuntu 32 bit. Any ideas?

EDIT: ADDED right here the ctest.c code ( i think there might be some errors here)

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ctype.h>          
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>


#define PORT 20000
#define LENGTH 512 

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_testcli_stdErr
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj)

{
    const char *msg = NULL;

    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_testcli_cliFromC
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj)

{
    /* Variable Definition */
    int sockfd; 
    int nsockfd;
    char revbuf[LENGTH]; 
    struct sockaddr_in remote_addr;
    //struct hostent *server; // per la parte scritta da me

    /* Get the Socket file descriptor */
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to obtain Socket Descriptor! (errno = %d)\n",errno);
        exit(1);
    }


    /* Fill the socket address struct */
    remote_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    remote_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    /*questo lo faccio così perchè localhost è 127.0.0.1, nel caso in cui debba recuperare l'ip dall'hostname uso la parte commentata sopra*/
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &remote_addr.sin_addr); //metto in remote_addr.sin_addr l'indirizzo ip 127.0.0.1 nel formato desiderato



    bzero(&(remote_addr.sin_zero), 8);

    /* Try to connect the remote */
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to connect to the host! (errno = %d)\n",errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    else 
        printf("[Client] Connected to server at port %d...ok!\n", PORT);

/* Send File to Server */
    //if(!fork())
    //{
        char* fs_name = "/home/elia/Desktop/project/tesi/PublicKey1";
        char sdbuf[LENGTH]; 
        printf("[Client] Sending %s to the Server... ", fs_name);
        FILE *fs = fopen(fs_name, "r");
        if(fs == NULL)
        {
            printf("ERROR: File %s not found.\n", fs_name);
            exit(1);
        }

        bzero(sdbuf, LENGTH); 
        int fs_block_sz; 
        while((fs_block_sz = fread(sdbuf, sizeof(char), LENGTH, fs)) > 0)
        {
            if(send(sockfd, sdbuf, fs_block_sz, 0) < 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to send file %s. (errno = %d)\n", fs_name, errno);
                break;
            }
            bzero(sdbuf, LENGTH);
        }
        printf("Ok File %s from Client was Sent!\n", fs_name);
    //}
    close (sockfd);
    printf("[Client] Connection lost.\n");
    return (0);

}
```

Comment: IIRC Java doesn't use the linker path when looking for libraries, it uses the class-path.

Comment: The code you added to the bashrc - did you log out and log in after you added it? Did you just add it to the file or did you also execute it in your current shell?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg in this case i don't know what to do, if u can suggest me something i'll be very gratefull (i added the library path cause without it, when i would execute "java testcli" it gave me the error can't find xxxx in java.library.path

Comment: @RealSkeptic I controlled via java -XshowSettings:properties that this path is in java.library.path, and yes, i restarted pc after it :)

Comment: OK, I tried to do the same as you (only with my own code as you didn't provide the ctest.c code), and other than having to add `-fpic` to the `gcc` command, it worked. Are you absolutely sure that you gave the correct path on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Please `echo` it and add the result to your question.

Comment: :/home/elia/Desktop/project2/thesys/src

Comment: posed source code in main answer of ctest.c if it helps

Comment: with -fpic option it gives me the error:"Could not find or load main class testcli"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, everything is fine. The error comes from your `stdErr()` function, and it actually shows it is working. I get the same error. Why does this happen?

```c
const char *msg = NULL;

perror(msg);
exit(1);
```

This prints the last error that was caused in the program. Now, you should only use `perror()` if you actually had an error in your program. Otherwise, it will print the message of  whatever was in the `errno` variable previously.

`errno` may have been set by something inside Java itself. It may have been looking for some file, but its non-existence is not a problem for Java so it continued to work. But `errno` is set to that value and keeps that value, and that's what's printed in your program.

To prove this, I have added the following to your `testcli.java`:

```java
public native void clearErr();
```

And my `main` is:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new testcli().clearErr();
    new testcli().stdErr();
    new testcli().cliFromC();

}
```

And to `ctest.c` I added:

```c
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_testcli_clearErr
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj)

{
    errno = 0;
}
```

Did the `javac`, `javah` and `gcc` again, ran the program, and now I get:

```
Success
```

Note that your third method is not called because of the `exit()` in `stdErr()`.

Comment: Thx you very much, it solved my problem. Now i've encountered the problem you mentioned about exit(). How can i let the stderr message work and let my client socket application too?

Comment: And i didnt say enough thx to you for the time you spent for helping me, i really really appreciate it

Comment: Well, either you call your `stdErr()` method only when you want to print the latest C error and exit, or you remove the `exit()` and call `System.exit()` from Java if you need to. I think it would be best if you take a look at other people's JNI code and see how they handle errors, because I'm pretty sure calling exit() from within JNI code is not good practice.

Comment: Again I don't know how to thank you enough, wish all the best for you :)